# Does pallet_identity require a migration if pallet_identity::simple::IdentityInfo is used as the InformationProvider type?

Tags: storage-migration, pallet-identity

Recently the pallet_identity added the InformationProvider type which defines the structure  to be used to store identity information. Am I right to think that no migration is required  for the pallet if pallet_identity::simple::IdentityInfo is used as the InformationProvider type, as it is the same structure as it was hardcoded before?